# How can I download a zip file with a custom extension?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, silverlight

Most Indian companies block many sites and downloads like for zip and exe files. I found a solution to explore the zip file in Google Docs extentions and it works with most of zip files formats, but its very lengthy to download or copy files one by one.

How can I download a zip file from a URL with alternate extentions using C#?

I am not looking for a proxy. A solution for websites only is also acceptable. I will make those changes on my site and than the site will alow the user to download the file using other extension.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what exactly you're doing, but you can always download the download the bytes of the file, then you whatever you need, including saving it with a new file extension.

Comment: ext zip is blocked thru proxy policy. did you get now. we cant download zip directly..

Answer (score 0):

`WebClient` makes it pretty easy to download files.

```
string query = "http://website.com/my.zip"
string output = "C:/Downloads";
using (var client = new WebClient())
{
    client.DownloadFile(query, output);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: hay dear i know this thing. but please read the question first and try to give answer. the extionsions are blocked.